# Quiero saber como se redacta una pregunta

Tags: ortografía

Quiero preguntarle a alguien. Hola, mañana, habrá clases o la manera correcta es hola, .mañana habrá clases?

Comment: Por favor, redactá la pregunta de forma más clara. No se puede terminar de entender.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de expresarlo según la intención. Esto se ve reflejado con las pausas cuando lo pronuncias o en la admiración y sorpresa que sientes al decirlo. Sin embargo, hay ciertas reglas ortográficas que sí hay que aprender como:

- En el español siempre se usan signos de apertura y cierre para las
  interrogaciones (¿?) y exclamaciones (¡!).
- Después de los signos de cierre antes mencionados (?!) **no** es escribe
  punto final/seguido/a parte, pues ya lo incluyen estos, por ello, la
  siguiente palabra empezará con mayúscula. Sin embargo, sí puede
  llevar otros signos después de los de cierre, por ejemplo *punto y
  coma*, *coma*, *puntos suspensivos* y la siguiente palabra comenzará
  según la regla ortográfica que corresponda.

[Esta página](https://www.rae.es/dpd/signos%20de%20interrogaci%C3%B3n%20y%20exclamaci%C3%B3n) de la RAE te puede ayudar sobre cuándo utilizar los signos y cómo deberían ir.

Aquí algunos ejemplos de cómo se puede escribir tu pregunta:

> Hola, ¿mañana habrá clases?

> Hola. ¿Mañana habrá clases?

> ¡Hola! ¿Mañana habrá clases?

> ¡Hola!, ¿mañana habrá clases?

> ¿Hola?, ¿mañana habrá clases? (no muy común, pero preguntando primero si hay alguien ahí).

En lo personal, prefiero las primeras dos formas para una conversación casual, pues con signos de admiración se ve muy formal o de libro de aprendizaje, como si tuvieras una sonrisa forzada.

Comment: *Los signos de admiración son como el catarro: hay que quitárselos de encima lo antes posible. Si el autor de El gran Gatsby, F. Scott Fitzgerald, creía que usar un signo de exclamación es “como reírte de tu propio chiste”, en castellano la broma es [doble](https://www.nytimes.com/es/2018/05/12/espanol/opinion/opinion-stavans-signo-exclamacion-espanol.html).*

Answer (score 0):

El modo correcto es separar las oraciones con signo de admiración para el saludo e interrogación para la pregunta:

> ¡Hola! ¿Mañana habrá clases?